# custom wordpress comment form html

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to modify the actual HTML of the comment forms in WordPress. I know of the `comment_form()` function that WordPress provides, but it doesn't actually let me modify the html of the form. What I'm specifically trying to do is make a bootstrap responsive form, which is not possible with the options provided with the `comment_form()` function. I've tried looking all over the internet for a way, but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Let me clarify this:

I am looking to modify the actual FORM and containing DIV elements of the comment form, not just the fields.

Comment: Without getting verbosely into the lack of separation of concerns plaguing wordpress in general, I'd just like to throw it out there that capturing the existing form with `ob_start()`/`ob_get_clean()` and then filtering for customizations with `DOMDocument` is a pretty viable way to edit most of the opinionated direct html output within wordpress, particularly if you are not super interested in the impossible-to-recycle-anything-spaghetti-plague that is the Loop.

Comment: Just use `ob_start();
comment_form();
$comment_form = ob_get_clean();` and you got it as a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The uncustomizable parts of the function `comment_form()` should (idealistically) be limited purely to code that is essential for security and proper form handling by the WordPress core. However, that is not the case. To explore the issue, I used filters (could have used arguments) to completely remove all the code that is customizable. I set all available variables to empty strings—that is, all the stuff mentioned on the codex page for `comment_form()`.

Here is the left-over, non-customisable code from `comment_form()`:

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
    <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"> <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/1#respond" style="display:none;">Click here to cancel reply.</a></small></h3>
    <form action="http://www.[yourdomain].com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="" class="comment-form">
        <p class="form-submit">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="" value="" />
            <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='1' id='comment_post_ID' />
            <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
        </p>
    </form>
</div><!-- #respond -->
```

Where does all this come from? At the bottom of the codex page for `comment_form()` it says…

> **Source Code**

> `comment_form()` is located in **wp-includes/comment-template.php**.

`comment-template.php` is linked and you can view the full code in the browser. `comment_form()` starts on line 1960. In fact, it’s the last function in that file. There are no arguments or filters that let you modify the residual code above. These lines of code are all moreorless “hard-coded”.

The text **Click here to cancel reply.** is the only text that survived my filter genocide. Strangely, `comment_form()` has back-up text for `cancel_reply_link` hard-coded into the function, in case it is passed to the function as an empty string. None of the other filterable items have hard-coded back-ups.

It is easy to see which bits of code are essential and which bits are non-essential for a HTML form. A little more difficult to judge is which bits are essential for a *WordPress* form. Some of the bits above were dynamically output (note that this is the first comment on a development blog with no other replies, no parent/child comments).

From the `comment_form()` function in `comment-template.php` you can draw out the code needed to produce the dynamic parts of the WordPress form. Then, with default arguments taken from the codex page for `comment_form()`, you could piece together a barebones form, hard-coding the desired fields, labels and wrapping HTML. I’m doing that now and putting my custom form function in my theme’s `comments.php` template file, which I call using `comments_template()` only in `single.php` (for this particular theme).

The result would be a full and proper, lean and mean WordPress comment form. But… it would be a form that could not be customized anymore using `comment_form()` arguments or related filters unless you went ahead and included the filter code in your own comment form function. Since you’re customizing the heck out it already, that’s probably not a problem. Similarly, all the WordPress actions would also be unavailable to you or any other plugins unless you also triggered those action functions in your own comment form function. Again, probably not an issue for you at this point.

But most importantly, the resulting form might break your theme if future WordPress updates change the way the core handles forms.

If you’re aware of those risks, you can probably rebuild a hand-coded comment form just from copying code on the [codex page for `comment_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) and in [wp-includes/comment-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php). I don’t have the finished code, otherwise I’d post it. But I will post when/if I succeed.

Right, that’s all from me for now. Bear in mind (all readers) that despite appearances, I am an amateur WordPress theme developer and my proficiency with PHP and WordPress is very rudimentary. Just writing up this post I learned a lot.

I’m also worried that a full and proper solution is already out there somewhere but I haven’t found it in my searches.

Comment: Also, if you still want to use comment-related plugins, you might want to consider including `do_action('comment_form_after_fields');` inside the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a New PHP file with the name of comment_form.php then paste all of your code. And your comment form is ready.

you shouldn't edit the wp-includes/comment-template.php file.

Keep this for your ref for more styling your existing comment form

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comment_form

Or this one

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-to-find-the-comment_form-function-in-wp3

**Form code and action**

```
<div class="comment-form">
            <h2 class="comments-wrapper-heading"> Leave a comment </h2>
            <form id="commentform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
              <div class="commentform-element">
                <label class="hide" for="author">Full Name</label>
                <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="commentform-element">
                <label class="hide" for="author">Email</label>
                <input class="input-fields" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="commentform-element">
                <label class="hide" for="comment">Message</label>
                <textarea id="comment" class="input-fields" placeholder="Message" name="comment" cols="40" rows="200"></textarea>
              </div>
              <input name="submit" class="form-submit-button"  type="submit" id="submit-comment" value="Post comment">
              <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="22" id="comment_post_ID">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
            </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: it's unclear from your answer how to use custom form fields.

Comment: a comment_form.php file will not be loaded using `comment_form()`

Answer (score 1):

WP does not offer a way to create and use a **comment *form* template**. i.e.: as of 4.1.1, there's still no way to control *all* of the HTML markup that makes up the form. There are only ways to edit *parts* of it and that's by supplying arguments to `comment_form()`.

So, if you would like to edit the whole layout (e.g.: place some of the content side to side instead of on top of one another; replace some of the `<p>`with `<div>`), you're out of luck.

What can we do?

An option would be to borrow the whole `comment_form()` function from the WordPress codebase ([like this guy did](https://github.com/dimensionmedia/buddystrap/blob/master/functions-comments.php)): make a copy of the function in your theme, rename it, customize it and then call it in place of the vanilla function. That will work but there's a chance it might break on a future WordPress update if some of the inner workings of WP change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look for the comment_form() function in Wordpress code  to see if you can edit it ?

You'll also find some informations here :

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/editing-the-comment-form

Comment: Yeah, that only allows you to add an remove fields and various other text. It doesn't actually provide a way to change the wrapping HTML or css classes.

Answer (score 0):

This function uses the default form. You need to make a `comment-template.php` file in your theme and in that file you can make your form.
Now when you will call `comments_template()` you will get your made form instead of default form.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't help me with the form. How do I get it to post the data? What url do I post to? What post fields is it expecting? How do I automatically provide user details when a user is logged in?

Comment: Okay, search for comments.php in your theme, there replace comments_form() by your form. Your form action will be "<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php".

Comment: What are the field names? What are the mandatory fields? How do you deal with logged in users and logged out users? None of this is documented on the WordPress site as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the containing div (`<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">`). Have a look at the [comment-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L0)

The only thing you can change is the form ID. `'id_form' => 'commentform'`

You can make a responsive form without changing these elements.

Comment: Nope. I get how to modify the FIELDS. What I can't figure out is how to modify the actual containing div

Comment: I also need to modify the form element itself

Answer (score 0):

I've recently answered something similiar on WPSE. You can go and check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138132/31545)